# Hide nav menu when on login page in ANGULAR

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a routing module that has a LoginComponent on the login page I want to hide the `<app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>` when not logged in. I have tried to subscribe to new `BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);` however when I do this the boolean always seams to be false even when I login.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const contractModule = () => import('./contract/contract.module').then(x => x.ContractModule);

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'news/:newsId', component: NewsDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'news-manager', component: NewsManagerComponent },
   //... MORE PATHS  ... 
  // otherwise redirect to login
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

app.component.html

```
<body>
  <app-nav-menu *ngIf="isLoggedIn"></app-nav-menu>
  <div class="ml-3 mr-3">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</body>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  isLoggedIn = this.auth.loggedIn; //Should set isLoggedIn Property
  title = 'app';
}
```

employee.service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  public loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // {1}
  public employees: Employee[];

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) { }
  }
  login(formData) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "employees/login", formData);
  }
  changePassword(formData) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + "employees/ChangePassword", formData);
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log("Login clicked");
    this.userService.login(form.value).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
        this.userService.loggedIn.next(true); //Set loggin to true
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      },
      err => {
        if (err.status == 200) {
          this.toastr.info('Change password.', 'New account.')
        }
        else if (err.status == 401) {
          this.toastr.error('Incorrect username or password', 'Authentication failed.');
        }
        else {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: When you logged in using login method, then you can make loggedIn property to true. And based on this property you can check user is looged in or not. This is in very simple term

Comment: @GRD I have tried your idea however it is always false since the property loggin is changed in auth method and the app.component is rerendered first so when I change the loggin property to true it has no effect on the app.component

Comment: Make loggedIn property as `behaviorsubject`. and subscribe it inside component, then in userService login() method pass value as true like `this.loggedIn.next(true);` . default loggedIn property is like `loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)`

Comment: I have change the question to refflect the idea you are suggesting I have already tried it without success. the loggedIn always seems to be false. Thank you for your help @GRD

Comment: Where you have subscribed  loggedIn property ?

Comment: @GRD I am not sure what you mean by subscribed I have set the   isLoggedIn = this.auth.loggedIn;  in my app.component.ts file does this not work?